# Apple Pay. Required fields are missing while sending PKPaymentToken to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, authorize.net, applepay

The server to which I send the received PKPaymentToken returns an error:
"There was an error processing the payment data. Required fields are missing from decrypted data."
Payment is made through the Authorize.net
My colleague who works on Apple Pay integration on the web says that Merchant Validation should be implemented first. But I couldn't find any information about it for iOS. It looks like the data I'm sending should be enough, but it isn't.

Here is my code

PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController config

```
- (IBAction)applePayButtonPressed:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"applePayPressed");
PKPaymentRequest* request = [PKPaymentRequest new];
request.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.gamma.company";
request.currencyCode = @"USD";
request.countryCode = @"US";

NSString *totalValue = [_totalCostStaticField.text substringFromIndex:1];
NSDecimalNumber *totalAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: totalValue];
self.total = [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"ItsEasy services" amount:totalAmount type:PKPaymentSummaryItemTypeFinal];
request.supportedNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkDiscover, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa];

request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability3DS;
NSArray* summaryItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.total, nil];
request.paymentSummaryItems = summaryItems;

PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *paymentVC = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
if (!paymentVC) { NSLog(@"PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController ===== nil"); }
paymentVC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:paymentVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

}

Getting paymentData, adding extra parameters and sending to server

```
- (void) paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                    didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                             completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion {
NSError *error;

if (payment.token.paymentData)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:payment.token.paymentData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *cardName = payment.token.paymentMethod.displayName;
    NSString *m_CCLast4 = [cardName substringFromIndex: [cardName length] - 4];
    
    [parameters setObject:[self encodeStringTo64:jsonString] forKey:@"paymentData"];
    [parameters setObject:m_CCLast4 forKey:@"m_CCLast4"];
    
    [self submitWithApplePay:parameters]; // send paymentData with extra parameters to the server
    
    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"paymentData == 0");
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
}
```

}

Encoding to base64

```
- (NSString*)encodeStringTo64:(NSString*)fromString {
NSData *plainData = [fromString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String;
base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];

return base64String;
```

}

Comment: The question is no longer relevant. This code works.